# When should antibody/antigen be pluralised?

Tags: science, biology

I am doing my thesis corrections, and my examiner (an engineer) has different ideas about whether the word should be pluralised than those I am used to, as I am a non-biochemist, I wanted advice on the accepted practice.

When talking about multiple types of antibody I am used to people in my lab saying antibodies, however as my lab is very international I realise that the way we talk may be idiosyncratic.

> e.g. "within the polyclonal serum we found antibodies against a number
>   of targets";

but when we are talking about antibody of one type we use the singular;

> e.g. "the pipette contained 25mg/ml of SN607D8 antibody"

not

> "the pipette contained 25mg/ml of SN607D8 antibodies".

Is this correct? Are there any documents that lay out the grammar for such things?

Similarly when we are talking about multiple types of antigen we say antigens

> "the antibody bound specifically to HLA-A2, but non specifically to a
>   number of other antigens";

but when we are talking about a number of a single type of antigen we would use the singular

> "the cell had numerous HLA-A2 antigen on its surface"

not

> "the cell had numerous HLA-A2 antigens on its surface".

Again is this correct?

Comment: You're arguing that the question should be on a science site. / I've science degrees, so I'll add my **opinions** on how to handle the pluralisation issue later.

Comment: It seems "English Language and Usage" also gets plenty of questions about writing mathematics, writing computer code, and so on.  So why would we object to a question about writing biology?

Answer (score 2):

(1) Words used to describe agglomerations, like '**soup**'and '**gravy**',  can often be used in either non-count or count mode:

> "I've got soup on my shirt." [private communication]

..........

> 'Our hearty, easy-to-make Knorr gravies come in a variety of delicious
>   flavours.' [[Knorr®
>   advert](https://www.knorr.com/ca/en/products/knorr-gravies.html)]

With **antibody**, the same behaviour is found:

> 'the pipette contained 25mg/ml of SN607D8 antibody'

[non-count usage]

..........

> 'within the polyclonal serum we found antibodies against a number of
>   targets' [count usage, the plural form being used for 'types of
>   antibodies']

...........................

(2) A real complication arises however with how some terms, like **antibody** and **antigen**, are used. While we don't talk of a 'soup particle' or a 'gravy molecule', antibodies and antigens are etically discrete, and usage seeks to allow for this while failing to differentiate senses. While [Webster's New World College Dictionary, 5th Edition](https://www.yourdictionary.com/antibody) has:

> **antibody** noun pl. -bodies
>
> a specialized protein produced by certain lymphocytes

(and we'd speak of *a protein molecule*, not of course *a protein*, when meaning a single molecule)

YourDictionary has:

> **antibody** noun
>
> The definition of an antibody is a protein molecule that can be found
>   in the blood and ...

and [RHK Webster's](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/antibody) has

> **antibody** n pl. -bodies
>
> 1. any of numerous protein molecules produced by B cells as a primary immune defense, each kind having a uniquely shaped site that combines
>      with a foreign antigen, as of a virus or bacterium, and disables it.

licensing '*antibody*' to be used interchangeably with '*individual antibody molecule*'. This is a second count usage, and this situation is more confusing than the corresponding situation with say *coffee* ('The two coffees grown are arabica and robusta' v "Two coffees, please!") or *cat* ('Jaguars and pumas are two less well-known cats' v 'Two cats were fighting in the street').

With 'virus', the situation is clarified by using the term 'virion' for a single entity. The situation really needs rationalising elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In general, both the terms– *antibody* and *antigen*, refer to classes of functional biomolecules (with the former being more specific) and are seldom used to mean individual molecules. The plural form denotes the different types.

> "within the polyclonal serum we found antibodies against a number of
>   targets"

This usage is fine. However, when referring to polyclonal antibody against a particular protein (not epitopes), you just use the singular form even though it is a mix of different monoclonal antibodies. For e.g. *polyclonal antibody against actin*. In this case, the term antibody refers to the formulation.

> "the pipette contained 25mg/ml of SN607D8 antibody"

This is correct as it refers to the concentration of a specific antibody.

> "the cell had numerous HLA-A2 antigen(s) on its surface".

Both usages are incorrect. Again, this statement uses the term *antigen* to describe different copies of the same molecule. In case of HLA, you should use the term *MHC/HLA receptors* if you want to indicate the different protein molecules/complexes on the cell surface. You can also use the term *copies* to mean many molecules of the same type. When you want to talk about HLA polymorphism you should use the terms *variants* or *alleles*.

You can use the plural form to describe different types of antigens. For e.g. *the bacteria has several antigens on its cell wall*.

Comment: "An antigen refers to an epitope." could you clarify? My understanding was that an epitope is a region on the surface of the antigen where the antibody binds.

Comment: @Abijah "antigen" means something that can bind to an antibody. It is an archaic term. By that statement, I meant that antigen doesn't mean a protein molecule. It means some molecular entity that can elicit an immune response by binding to an antibody. You are right: epitope is a part of the molecule that the antibody binds. I'll clarify